# Automatic line break in (sub-)section name and toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyphenation

I have some long one-word subsection titles that (partly) dont get hyphenated correctly in the title itself and the toc.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
           top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]
           {geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty,ragged2e}
\allsectionsfont{\RaggedRight}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}

\subsection{Ethyl (5\textit{R},6\textit{E},8\textit{E})-2-hydroxy-5-[(2-methoxyethoxy)methoxy]-\textit{N}-methoxy-\textit{N}-methyldeca-6,8-dienoat}

\subsection{Dimethyl 2-[(4\textit{S})-4-benzyl-2-oxo-1,3-oxazolidin-3-yl]-2-oxoethylphosphonat}

\end{document}
```

This MWE leads me to:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try with explicit hyphenation: `\-`

Comment: The hyphenation algorithm algorithm has problems with some of your texts. Try specifying where the hyphens could go. See the `\hyphenation` macro for use in the preamble.